# Correct path structure to open JSON object using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to create a "mock API" module in JS, so I want to request data from a source (`products.json`) via a url like `myapi.com/get/products`. It doesn't have to be a legitimate API.

I have this working using an example JSON object from http://www.jsontest.com - but I'm not sure how to do this with my own external data, `products.json`

My function:

```
var displayProductList = (function() {
    var productList = {
        init: function(uri) {
            this.getData(uri);
        },
        getData: function(uri) {
            $.ajax({
                context: this,
                dataType: 'json',
                url: uri,
                success: this.runOutput
            });
        },
        runOutput: function(data) {
            ...
        }
    }
    productList.init('http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two');
})();
```

This works OK (I can't run it from JSFiddle as it's not https, but it should work): https://jsfiddle.net/xou1k8y8/1/

So my question is, how would I replace the URL in my code with the path to my directory `get/products.json` and be able to access the data therein?

For example:

```
productList.init('localhost/my-project/get/products.json');
```

Doing the above doesn't work. I've also tried adding `/products` so I can access the `products` JSON data below.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{"products":[
    {
        "id":"0001",
        "title":"The Jungle Book",
        "price":"13.60",
        "currency":"GBP",
        "isbn":"978-0062389503",
        "stock":{
            "in-stock":"yes",
            "stock-quantity":"98"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Are you running a webserver on localhost?

Comment: @Barmar as localhost. I am also trying to test on my server but it's down at present so I can only work with localhost.

Comment: @user1486133 You can't access client-side files with AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Your localhost URL is not correct. You need to put `//` before the hostname in a URL, otherwise it's treated as a directory name.

```
productList.init('//localhost/my-project/get/products.json');
```

Note that because of the AJAX same-domain restriction, you can only do this when you loaded the HTML file from `http://localhost`.

Comment: Not sure if browser will allow AJAX on localhost at all.

Comment: @skobaljic — Of course it will. It's a hostname, like any other.

Comment: I added more information about it having to be the same as where the HTML page came from.

Comment: Correct, I had troubles with running ajax on usb stick, than had to install server.

Comment: @Barmar I have attempted with the full URL:     `productList.init('http://localhost:8888/my-project/get/products.json');` and then `console.log(data)` in `runOutput` but I get nothing - although no errors.

Comment: @Barmar nope. When I had my URL incorrectly I did get an error. Now i just get nothing, which suggests the start of the URL is fine but I'm not adding the right request to the end of the URL to get the `product` data in the JSON

Comment: @Barmar no I'm not getting any response in network tab. Nor is my data outputting to the console

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it would say that the AJAX is successful, but there wouldn't be anything in the Response. Are you sure the JSON is in the file?

Answer (score -1):

Simply switch the URL for your file path:

> ```
>     getData: function(uri) {
>         $.ajax({
>             context: this,
>             dataType: 'json',
>             url: 'get/products.json',
>             success: this.runOutput
>         });
>     },
> ```

Simple as that c:

Comment: As you can see I'm instead using `this` and then adding the URL I want to request to the `init` - my problem is understanding what the URL pattern should be to access the JSON as I've laid out in the OP